# How to set actual font to pdf file using itext7 library?

Tags: java, itext7

I have a problem when I added a `PdfFont` by `itext7` library and that font not embedded a pdf reader added `actual font` to my created font and when I write some text in fillable fields in this pdf by default used that `actual font` which differs from mine.
How can I fix this issue?

that is my code for creating font:

```
PdfFont pdfFont = PdfFontFactory.createFont(fileName, embed);
PdfTextFormField pdfField = PdfFormField.createText(pdf, rect, "MyTextField", "", pdfFont, 16f);
```

and that is screenshot of information about fonts:
[image]
and `actual font` in that case is `Adobe Sans MM`. 
How can I remove or replace this property?

Comment: If you use a font in a PDF without embedding it and the PDF reader does not have access to a copy of that font, it can fail completely ("Error: your PDF requires resources not known to your reader") or it can try with a different font instead. Your PDF viewer decides to try and use a different font. Thus, for non-embedded, unknown fonts, there is an actual font. If you don't want that, embed.

Comment: @mkl but if I want to set a custom font fo fillable field how can I do it? I couldn't embed my font because it doesn't work and I don't know what symbols would be using a user.

Comment: That's exactly the problem with custom fonts for form fields: If you are not sure that the user's PDF viewer has access to that font, you have to embed it. If it is too large for complete embedding, you have to subset and only embed some glyph ranges. To be able to select those ranges you have to know to a certain degree which characters the user will be using.

Comment: By the way... *"I couldn't embed my font because it doesn't work"* - more likely because you did something wrong...